# Random authentication error - oozie shell action in oozie workflow

Tags: shell, hive, kerberos, oozie

I am trying to execute around 30 oozie workflows each with below actions:

1. One Shell actions: to identify the last record updated in a set of 10 hive tables
2. 10 forked Sqoop actions:  to query the RDBMS for the records that were updated post that for the related table
3. 10 forked Hive actions: to merge the newly sqooped data with the respective hive table.

The below is the shell action part from the workflow xml file:

```
<start to="shell-node_SET10_wf_hive_tables"/>
    <action name="shell-node_SET10_wf_hive_tables">

        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">

            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>

            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            
            <exec>LAST_VALUE_10.sh</exec>
            <argument>${hive_table1}</argument>
            <argument>${hive_table2}</argument>
            <argument>${hive_table3}</argument>
            <argument>${hive_table4}</argument>
            <argument>${hive_table5}</argument>
            <argument>${hive_table6}</argument>
            <argument>${hive_table7}</argument>
            <argument>${hive_table8}</argument>
            <argument>${hive_table9}</argument>
            <argument>${hive_table10}</argument>
            <file>${last_value_script_path}#LAST_VALUE_10.sh</file>
            <file>${keytabpath}/${keytabaccount}#${keytabaccount}</file>
            <capture-output/>
        </shell>

        <ok to="forking"/>
        <error to="failed-notification-email_SET10_SHELL"/>
    </action>
```

The contents of the LAST_VALUE_10.sh bash script that is being called in the above shell action is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

kinit -kt XYZ_10.keytab XYZ@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM

last_val_temp1=`beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 --hiveconf mapreduce.job.queuename=TEST_QUEUE -u 'jdbc:hive2://ntd001:10000/'"hadoop_instance_1"';principal=hive/ntd001.ABC.DEF.GHI.COM@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM' -e "select max(ORA_ROWSCN) from $1"`
kinit -kt XYZ_10.keytab XYZ@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM
last_val_temp2=`beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 --hiveconf mapreduce.job.queuename=TEST_QUEUE -u 'jdbc:hive2://ntd001:10000/'"hadoop_instance_1"';principal=hive/ntd001.ABC.DEF.GHI.COM@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM' -e "select max(ORA_ROWSCN) from $2"`
kinit -kt XYZ_10.keytab XYZ@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM
last_val_temp3=`beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 --hiveconf mapreduce.job.queuename=TEST_QUEUE -u 'jdbc:hive2://ntd001:10000/'"hadoop_instance_1"';principal=hive/ntd001.ABC.DEF.GHI.COM@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM' -e "select max(ORA_ROWSCN) from $3"`
kinit -kt XYZ_10.keytab XYZ@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM
last_val_temp4=`beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 --hiveconf mapreduce.job.queuename=TEST_QUEUE -u 'jdbc:hive2://ntd001:10000/'"hadoop_instance_1"';principal=hive/ntd001.ABC.DEF.GHI.COM@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM' -e "select max(ORA_ROWSCN) from $4"`
kinit -kt XYZ_10.keytab XYZ@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM
last_val_temp5=`beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 --hiveconf mapreduce.job.queuename=TEST_QUEUE -u 'jdbc:hive2://ntd001:10000/'"hadoop_instance_1"';principal=hive/ntd001.ABC.DEF.GHI.COM@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM' -e "select max(ORA_ROWSCN) from $5"`
kinit -kt XYZ_10.keytab XYZ@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM
last_val_temp6=`beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 --hiveconf mapreduce.job.queuename=TEST_QUEUE -u 'jdbc:hive2://ntd001:10000/'"hadoop_instance_1"';principal=hive/ntd001.ABC.DEF.GHI.COM@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM' -e "select max(ORA_ROWSCN) from $6"`
kinit -kt XYZ_10.keytab XYZ@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM
last_val_temp7=`beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 --hiveconf mapreduce.job.queuename=TEST_QUEUE -u 'jdbc:hive2://ntd001:10000/'"hadoop_instance_1"';principal=hive/ntd001.ABC.DEF.GHI.COM@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM' -e "select max(ORA_ROWSCN) from $7"`
kinit -kt XYZ_10.keytab XYZ@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM
last_val_temp8=`beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 --hiveconf mapreduce.job.queuename=TEST_QUEUE -u 'jdbc:hive2://ntd001:10000/'"hadoop_instance_1"';principal=hive/ntd001.ABC.DEF.GHI.COM@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM' -e "select max(ORA_ROWSCN) from $8"`
kinit -kt XYZ_10.keytab XYZ@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM
last_val_temp9=`beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 --hiveconf mapreduce.job.queuename=TEST_QUEUE -u 'jdbc:hive2://ntd001:10000/'"hadoop_instance_1"';principal=hive/ntd001.ABC.DEF.GHI.COM@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM' -e "select max(ORA_ROWSCN) from $9"`
kinit -kt XYZ_10.keytab XYZ@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM
last_val_temp10=`beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 --hiveconf mapreduce.job.queuename=TEST_QUEUE -u 'jdbc:hive2://ntd001:10000/'"hadoop_instance_1"';principal=hive/ntd001.ABC.DEF.GHI.COM@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM' -e "select max(ORA_ROWSCN) from ${10}"`
kinit -kt XYZ_10.keytab XYZ@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM




[ "$last_val_temp1" = "NULL" ] && last_val_temp_1=0 || last_val_temp_1=$last_val_temp1
[ "$last_val_temp2" = "NULL" ] && last_val_temp_2=0 || last_val_temp_2=$last_val_temp2
[ "$last_val_temp3" = "NULL" ] && last_val_temp_3=0 || last_val_temp_3=$last_val_temp3
[ "$last_val_temp4" = "NULL" ] && last_val_temp_4=0 || last_val_temp_4=$last_val_temp4
[ "$last_val_temp5" = "NULL" ] && last_val_temp_5=0 || last_val_temp_5=$last_val_temp5
[ "$last_val_temp6" = "NULL" ] && last_val_temp_6=0 || last_val_temp_6=$last_val_temp6
[ "$last_val_temp7" = "NULL" ] && last_val_temp_7=0 || last_val_temp_7=$last_val_temp7
[ "$last_val_temp8" = "NULL" ] && last_val_temp_8=0 || last_val_temp_8=$last_val_temp8
[ "$last_val_temp9" = "NULL" ] && last_val_temp_9=0 || last_val_temp_9=$last_val_temp9
[ "${last_val_temp10}" = "NULL" ] && last_val_temp_10=0 || last_val_temp_10=${last_val_temp10}

printf "last_val_1=$last_val_temp_1\nlast_val_2=$last_val_temp_2\nlast_val_3=$last_val_temp_3\nlast_val_4=$last_val_temp_4\nlast_val_5=$last_val_temp_5\nlast_val_6=$last_val_temp_6\nlast_val_7=$last_val_temp_7\nlast_val_8=$last_val_temp_8\nlast_val_9=$last_val_temp_9\nlast_val_10=${last_val_temp_10}"
```

It is the same format for all my 30 workflows with each importing 10 tables. each of these workflows have a unique LAST_VALUE script and i have duplicated the keytab file 30 times with each unique keytab filename being used by one workflow. i have scheduled these with my oozie coordinator to start them with 15 mins of delay between each workflow once a day.

I see that randomly some workflows fail each day with the same below error. The workflow that fails today succeeds in the next run, but fails randomly may be 10 days or so down the line. Each day one or two workflows fail which have been running successfully for some days, but with the same error all the time.

Error:

```
[main] INFO com.unraveldata.agent.ResourceCollector - Unravel Sensor 4.5.1.1rc0013/1.3.11.3 initializing.
./LAST_VALUE_10.sh: line 3: kinit: command not found
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
scan complete in 2ms
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://ntd001:10000/hadoop_instance_1;principal=hive/ntd001.ABC.DEF.GHI.COM@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM
20/10/08 02:31:12 [main]: ERROR transport.TSaslTransport: SASL negotiation failure
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslClientTransport.java:94)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:271)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1924)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport.open(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:203)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:168)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:146)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:211)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1529)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1424)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:52)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.execCommandWithPrefix(BeeLine.java:1139)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.dispatch(BeeLine.java:1178)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.initArgs(BeeLine.java:818)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.begin(BeeLine.java:898)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.mainWithInputRedirection(BeeLine.java:518)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.main(BeeLine.java:501)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:141)
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:122)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:224)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192)
    ... 35 more
Unknown HS2 problem when communicating with Thrift server.
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://ntd001:10000/hadoop_instance_1;principal=hive/ntd001.ABC.DEF.GHI.COM@ABC.DEF.GHI.COM: GSS initiate failed (state=08S01,code=0)
No current connection
```

I am not able to pinpoint the reason for such random failures and need help in identifying it and to fix the same. I tried multiple things like forking the shell action in each workflow with a bash script querying only one hive table, etc...but not able to solve it.

Comment: _"random failures  … `kinit: command not found`"_ > this means your System Admins are clowns; on one of the Hadoop nodes, the service account that runs the Shell action does not have the same settings for PATH env variables as on the other nodes.

Comment: Did you check on which node the Action was running when it failed? My guess is it's always the same node, or couple of nodes.

Comment: Either ask your System Admins to clean up their mess, or use an **absolute path** for `kinit` e.g. `/usr/bin/kinit` on RedHat & friends.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter - Thanks. I will enquire with the sysadmin.